# How to know if a window is a child or parent window?

Tags: javascript

How can a browser window know if it is a parent window or a child window using JavaScript?

I was hoping to make use of this in a conditional.

```
if(parentWindow){//..
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if( window !== top ) 
    //then you are a child of something
```